# Use drag and drop feature to fill input box value

Tags: input, textbox, drag-and-drop, ngmodel

The input or textbox should change its value , when users drags and drops a text onto the text area. 
    User manual entry is also avoided by preventing keyboard strokes.

**Html for drag & drop**

```
<input (keydown)="preventKeyboard($event)" (drop)="fieldDrop($event)" class="k-textbox" [(ngModel)]="field">

<p draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">field</p>
```

**Handers for drag, drop & user key entry prevention**

```
drag(ev) {                                      //drag
  ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
}

fieldDrop(ev) {                                 //drop
  let data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.currentTarget.innerHTML = data;
}

preventKeyboard(e) {                            //prevent user key entry
let evt = e || window.event;
if (evt) {
  let keyCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
  if (evt.preventDefault) {
      evt.preventDefault();
  } else {
      evt.returnValue = false;
  }
 }
}
```

Upon dragging, value is changed incorrectly.

Say if current value of input box is "abc" and then if "def" is dropped in box, the value is changed to "abcdef" instead of "def".

Comment: Plz debbug to see if your fieldDrop fires when dropping the text, because i think the action in dropping is built in.

Comment: It does get called. But would not reflect

Comment: Added an answer tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

Use `setData` to save the data instead of `getData` that gives you the saved data

Your dragStart() function should be:

```
drag(ev) {                                     
 ev.dataTransfer.setData
("text",ev.currentTarget.innerHTML);
}
```